# How to find delay of circuit?

Tags: fpga, xilinx, vivado, vivado-hls

How to find delay, throughput, maximum operating frequency for my circuit in vivado?
The values that I have are Worst Negative slack=2.055 ns, Total negative slack of 0ns, number of failing end points=0, total number of end points=22082.

Answer (score 0):

Delay and throughput depend on your design. The slack suggests that your max frequency is about 2ns faster than what it is now.